# Styling issue with Zopim widget

Tags: javascript, css

I have installed Zopim widget on my website (by adding its code in the head section), but It always loads with a black color theme regardless of what color I have chosen. I have also tried to set the styles using CSS and Javascript manually but no success. The website address is: [www.caferobot.ir/store1](http://caferobot.ir/store1/) (It is Magento based)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the black background by this class: *content jx_ui_Widget*, or this ID: *___$_11__content*.

Well, you can try to set the background to none, or transparent, but I don't think you will achieve something. Maybe plugin is out-dated, try to install new or another one.

Comment: I have tried to add this at the end of <body> section but no success: 'document.getElementsByClassName("example").style.color="#F37021"' but no success. I have also done it using ID but nothing changed.

Comment: Try to use !important class in CSS. If this won't work, then I think if should be something in the plugin source code.

Comment: Actually I do not have access to the CSS styling (It is loaded from another server through a code). This widget works fine on my Joomla website. So I think there is a conflict with the theme or other scripts But I do not know how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Zopim's API?

```
// Example
$zopim(function() {
    $zopim.livechat.theme.setColors({badge: '#FFFFFF', primary: '#000000'});
    $zopim.livechat.theme.reload(); // apply new theme settings
});
```

[Link to Zopim Javascript API](https://api.zopim.com/files/meshim/widget/controllers/liveChatAPI/Theme-js.html)

Also, Zopim's live chat widget runs in an `<iframe>`, so any css or javascript from its parent window will not affect it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for that (using Zopim API):
http://modernminds.nl/zopim-configuration-customize-api/

You can add the variables/colors you want and paste the code below the Zopim code to customize your widget (per site).

Comment: Please stop linking to http://modernminds.nl/zopim-configuration-customize-api/. This might be perceived as spam and get you banned from answering questions on Stack Overflow **for good**.

Comment: thanks for the warning, @dorukayhan, but we've created this tool free of charge for everyone to use, because the Zopim API is not easily accessible to a lot of people. No commercial incentive.